# elementary-sdk error

Tags: applications, apps

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 elementary-sdk : Depends: libgala-dev but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libgirepository1.0-dev but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libgranite-dev but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libgtk-3-dev but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libwingpanel-2.0-dev but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: valac but it is not going to be installed

Comment: Yikes! after running sudo apt-get upgrade -f I got this:

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies

Comment: sudo apt-cache policy libgtk2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev
libgtk2.0-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2
  Version table:
     2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2.24.30-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages

Comment: libglib2.0-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.48.2-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     2.48.2-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2.48.0-1ubuntu4 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages

Comment: Are you on elementary OS Loki stable? Do you have any third-party PPAs added?

Comment: yes on Loki stable. Yes I do have PPAs. Should I remove/disable them?

Comment: Ok I disabled all PPAS. However that still did not fix the issue. When I run sudo apt-get install elementary-sdk I get the same error as before of having unmet dependencies. Then there is the issue of this package "grub-efi-amd64-signed" not ever updating/installing.

Comment: Ok I got a little further this time. When I try to compile the code I get this error now. fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: cc exited with status 256

Comment: It says that I need to install libgtk-3-dev but when I try I get the same dependency BS.

Comment: so here is the latest error while trying to install libgtk-3-dev.
libpng12-dev : Depends: libpng12-0 (= 1.2.54-1ubuntu1) but 1.2.54-5x0~ppa is to be installe